# Allowing cross domain ajax requests with Meteor

Tags: javascript, ajax, meteor, cors

**Server side setup**

```
JsonRoutes.setResponseHeaders({
  "Cache-Control": "no-store",
  "Pragma": "no-cache",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With"
});
```

**Client side setup**

```js
  var getRecentPosts = function (token) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:3000/publications/recentPostsAndComments",
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      // contentType: "application/json",
      success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        debugger
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, err) {
        debugger
      }
    });
  }
```

I always get caught inside the `error` callback because of the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/publications/recentPostsAndComments. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Is there anything noticeable that I am missing here?

**Update:**

in the network tab, I see one `option` request that succeeds, but I don't see a `GET` request that's supposed to be sent.

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/publications/recentPostsAndComments
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Response Headers
view source
connection:keep-alive
content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8
date:Sat, 19 Sep 2015 23:53:48 GMT
transfer-encoding:chunked
vary:Accept-Encoding
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ko;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:3000
Origin:http://localhost:5000
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:5000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: is server set up to receive OPTIONS requests? The CORS headers need to be sent out on those requests. Inspect actual requests sent in browser dev tools network for more clues

Comment: server clearly not setting proper headers on that OPTIONS request. Also if needing to send credentials should probably set `withCredentials` header on client side

Comment: That was indeed the case. Thank you for giving me tips to debug. 1) checking the response header in the pre-flight OPTIONS request was the critical tip. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it! Thank you.

Comment: actually might be best for you to post answer with the fix also. Will have longer term benefit for others with similar issues

Answer (score -2):

This is what I sometimes use and it works great.

//Server Side PHP

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 2000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-   Requested-With');
?>
```

As you know, it should be placed before any code....